# What does this decode to, and is it UTF? Ð˜Ð³Ð¾Ñ€Ñœ

Tags: encoding, utf

I have received this in a name field (so it should be a person's name)
Ð˜Ð³Ð¾Ñ€Ñœ

What could that decode to? Is it UTF-8? What language does that translate to? Russian?

If you can give me a hint or maybe links to websites that explain what meaningful letters I should get out of that would be helpful, thank you :)

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typically is UTF-8 interpreted as some single-byte Windows encoding.

```
        String s = "Ð˜Ð³Ð¾Ñ€Ñœ"; // Source encoding UTF-8
        byte[] b = s.getBytes("Cp1252");
        System.out.println("" + new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        // Игорќ
```

The data might easily get corrupted. Above I got some results with Windows-1252 (MS Windows Latin-1). The java source must be compiled with encoding UTF-8 to accept those chars.

Comment: I asked a native russian speaking friend, and she says that this: Игорь is a name and not this: Игорќ

so instead of ќ it should return ь 
Is there a table that shows which letters should convert to what please?

Comment: @user3672795 There like a hundred single byte encodings, many of which only differ in a few characters. Just forget about them all and use UTF-8.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález can you link me to somewhere please for all these byte encodings? Because I need to be precise in the names

Comment: @user3672795 Well, you have the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) but I can't understand why you need that. Your data is UTF-8, you don't need other encodings.

Comment: @user3672795 Looking at the last character: it is U+045C which according to the Unicode standard is CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER KJE and is used in Macedonian ... perhaps you need a wider circle of friends :-) ... Note that the ASCII equivalent of the first 4 characters is Igor -- looks like a name to me. And it was found in a name field? Case closed; you are going to get much worse rubbish than Igork in a name field

Comment: The cause of the KJE error can be a second wrong conversion of byte as char and then you have lost information. In general it is easier (for my mental health) to start all over again with the correct conversion, than trying to understand and undo the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already pasted the original code into a UTF-8 encoded site as Stack Overflow your code is now corrupt data perfectly encoded as UTF-8. If you want to ask yourself anything about the data encoding you need to use an hexadecimal editor or a similar tool on the original raw bytes.

In any case, if you do this:

1. Open a text file in some single-byte encoding (possibly the ANSI code page used by your copy of Windows, I used Windows-1252)
2. Paste the `Ð˜Ð³Ð¾Ñ€Ñœ` gibberish and save the file
3. Reload the file as UTF-8

... you get this:

```
Игорќ
```

So it's probably valid UTF-8 incorrectly decoded.

Comment: how do open a text file in single-byte encoding?

Comment: It depends on the editor. RJ TextEd, for instance, has an "Encoding"  drop-down in the "Open file" dialog.

Comment: so I got RJ TextEd, how can I use it to change the code in the text as you did?

Comment: In this case you can save the file as Windows-1252 or whatever and then chose "File/ Reopen with encoding/ UTF-8". But I was all the time under the impression that original file was just fine :-?

Comment: +1 for "If you want to ask yourself anything about the data encoding you need to use an hexadecimal editor or a similar tool on the original raw bytes" -1 for mucking about with source editors